# Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I get the follwing error: `Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()`

Somehow useAuth is called before firebase.initializeApp (according to doc it's a synchronous function) but I have no idea why. Could you give me a hint?

```js
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
}

export const authContext = createContext<{ authUser: firebase.User | null }>({
  authUser: null,
});

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const authUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    return { initializing: !authUser, authUser };
  });
  function onChange(authUser: any) {
    setState({ initializing: false, authUser });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // listen for auth state changes
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onChange);
    // unsubscribe to the listener when unmounting
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return state;
};

export default firebase;
```